# Vue.js watch DOM element property outside components / app

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue component nested in a regular website.

I would like to watch from the component if a DOM element is clicked outside of this component. this is just a regular HTML element NOT in a vue component

I can't use `v-on`. I also tried a regular event listener but that does not work either because it cannot access the component's property...

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add an event listener in `mounted()` of your component. Here's a fiddle I put together: https://jsfiddle.net/2kwjvtun/